# spark.cassandra.connection.connections_per_executor_max is not a valid spark cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm getting the following error when using cassandra connector 2.5.2:

```
spark.cassandra.connection.connections_per_executor_max is not a valid spark cassandra connector variable.
```

In cassandra connector 2.4 this param works fine.

Is there any equivalent option in cassandra connector 2.5.2?

Thanks!

Example in my code:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.connections_per_executor_max", 160)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see `spark.cassandra.connection.localConnectionsPerExecutor` and `spark.cassandra.connection.remoteConnectionsPerExecutor` configurations in [v2.5.2 documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v2.5.2/doc/reference.md#cassandra-connection-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

There was a significant change in the [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) where a lot of functionality that was previously only available to [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) customers was open-sourced in version 2.5.0 of the connector. Details are available in this blog post -- [Advanced Apache Cassandra Analytics Now Open For All](https://www.datastax.com/blog/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all).

Part of the move was to rename DSE parameters to bring them in line with the `spark.cassandra.*` naming convention ([SPARKC-575](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-575)). This included:

```
spark.cassandra.connection.localConnectionsPerExecutor
spark.cassandra.connection.remoteConnectionsPerExecutor
```

For the full list of connection parameters, see [the Configuration Reference for Spark Cassandra connector v2.5.2](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v2.5.2/doc/reference.md#cassandra-connection-parameters). Cheers!